# Outlook table border positioning

Tags: html, css, outlook, border, mjml

Trying out Mjml and ran into this problem where I am not able to place the border border exactly where it needs to be for my table to work. It is a bit DYI but it is the only way I have made it work so far with Outlook. My question is that can I somehow control the exact positioning of the border so I can align it perfectly to the image?

I will post my code below in MJML:

This is where I am able to get to this: [image of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RWhUI.png)

Outlook version, god help me here: [Outlook Html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NvLxI.png)

```
  <mj-wrapper>
   <mj-section background-color="#fff">
      <mj-column>
        <mj-table>
          <tr>
            <td style="padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;">
            <img src="./img/haut@2x.png" alt="couple-img" />
            </td>
          </tr>

          <tr style="border-left: 2px solid #702b7e;">

           <td align="center" style="padding:0px 40px 0px 40px;">
               <span style="font-family:Arial-BoldMT;font-size:18px;color:#702b7e;"> LE TÉMOIGNAGE </span> <br /> <br />
               <span style="font-family:Arial-BoldMT;font-size:16px;color:#6f6f6f;">Je vous présente Laure et Mathieu ! </span> <br />
               <span style="font-size:15px;color:#6f6f6f;">Ils viennent d’acheter un tout nouveau chauffe-eau thermodynamique et nous racontent comment il change leur vie, surtout à l’heure du bain avec leur trois enfants ! 
               Et en plus d’être plus écologique, il se révèle plus économique… mais je vais les laisser vous en parler
               </span> <br /> <br />
                <button style="border: 0;padding:18px;background-color:#7a2182;color:white;border-radius:26px;font-size:14px;">
                DÉCOUVRIR TOUS LES BÉNÉFICES
                </button>
           </td>
           <td>
           
           </td>
           <td align="center">
           </td>
           <td>
           </td>           
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
            <img src="./img/bas@2x.png" alt="" />
            </td>
          </tr>
        </mj-table>
      </mj-column>
    </mj-section>
     </mj-wrapper>
```

Answer (score 0):

The fact is that Outlook uses Word for rendering message bodies. For example, the `span` element supports a smaller subset of Word–supported cascading style sheets, defined by the term CORE. Read more about supported and unsupported HTML elements, attributes, and cascading style sheets properties in the [Word HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338201(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) article.